# Show a sequence of R-modules and R-homomorphisms is exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Suppose given a exact sequence, $$0 \to A\xrightarrow{\enspace f\enspace} B\xrightarrow{\enspace g\enspace} C\to 0$$
I want to show the sequence,$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ 
$$0→\Hom_R(N,A) \xrightarrow{\enspace f_*\enspace}\Hom_R(N,B)\xrightarrow{\enspace g_*\enspace} \Hom_R(N,C)$$ is also exact.

Here $f_*:\Hom_R(N,A)\to \Hom_R(N,B)$ is defined to be, $$f_*:f\mapsto h\circ f$$where $h$ is a $R$-homomorphism from $A$ to $B$.

I'm having trouble proving exactness at both points. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, I edited it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hom is a left-exact functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47401/hom-is-a-left-exact-functor). See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253636/proving-that-homn-is-left-exact)

Comment: $f_*$ should be defined as $$(h:N\to A)\longmapsto (f\circ h:N\to B)$$ and similarly for $g_*$.